# Slower HTTP 1.0 Communication on Windows Embedded Compact 7 (Formerly CE)

Tags: windows, http, sockets, embedded, windows-ce

on Windows Embedded Compact 7 (Formerly CE) I have a much slower performance responsing to HTTP 1.0 requests than on older Windows CE versions (4.0 and 5.0).
On Windows CE 5.0 I have about 10 ms to respond a request and on Embedded Compact 7 about 170 ms.
As soon as I switch to "Keep Alive" and  HTTP 1.1 its fast again.
But I want to understand if there was any new socket limitation or option option introducted that can be changed.

Comment: There are other factors to take into acount besindes the OS version, like hardware quality and driver sotfware (BSP) for example.

Comment: But I have two different hardware platforms with CE 7.0 and both of them are a lot slower. I cannot see another relevant factor than the OS in this situation. There must be a certain thing in the TCP/IP stack that has been changed. Maybe I have to increase the backlog size for the listen socket. I am going to test that. Other suggestions?

Comment: I suspect the difference is into the http headers. Can you dump the HTTP requests/responses of both devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you set TCPSendQueueDelay to 0 in the registry. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/ee495047.aspx)  The default setting is 4 (in ms), and in our application this caused significant delays when many small packets are being exchanged.  This is apparently a new setting in WEC7 which causes the tcp/ip performance to be much worse in the case of many small packets being exchanged.  This will reduce performance for some communication patterns, such as large blocks of data being sent fairly frequently. A Microsoft representative has confirmed to us that setting TCPSendQueueDelay causes WEC7's behavior to be the same as CE 5.0's.